# Date appearing one day before while export to excel using javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to do export excel using  [alasql](https://github.com/agershun/alasql) where I'm transforming the date that I'm getting from JSON **("10 Jun 2018")** to **MM/DD/YYYY (6/10/2018)**  format as shown below:

```
var date="12 Apr 2018";
function trandformDate(date){
return new Date(date);
}
```

However on export to excel I'm seeing the date 1 day less than the actual date ie.,**6/9/2018**[image]

I tried by incrementing the date by doing this..But didn't work

```
   var date="12 Apr 2018";
    function trandformDate(date){
    return new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1));
    }
```

Please let me know how can I get the exact date using javascript..thanks

Comment: It looks like you define the trandformDate function twice but never call it.

Comment: I haven't mentioned the call here.I have called it..

Comment: You should not use the built-in parser for non-standard string formats, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) A "JSON" date should be in ISO 8601 extended format like "2018-05-25T06:22:10.416Z".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your function once like so:

```
function trandformDate(dateString){ 
    var date = new Date(dateString);
    return new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1));
}
```

Then call it like this

```
var dateStr = "12 Apr 2018";
var date = trandformDate(dateStr); // Fri Apr 13 2018
```

Comment: Thanks @ale10ander But I'm getting time as well.Please let me know how can I remove that

Comment: @forgottofly You can call date.toDateString() to return just the date.